# Discrete mathematics - Rubiks cube permutation and unique states.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

> Define a move to be a $90$ degree turn of $1$ of the $6$ sides of the
>   cube clock-wise or counter-clockwise.
>
> So for a $3\times 3\times 3$ cube I know that the number of possible unique
>   states are $8!⋅12!⋅2^{10}\cdot 3^7.$ I have two questions:
>
> **1)** Say I start with a solved cube, using only $1$ move, how many different states can be achieved? What in about $2$ moves?
>
> **2)** The number of states that can be achieved in maximum $18$ moves is less than the total number of moves. How is this proven?

So for the first question, in $1$ move, each side can be turned in $2$ ways, so we get $2$ distinct states per side, which is a total of $2\cdot 6=12$ states.

Same reasoning with $2$ states but here we have to be careful because twisting one side twice clockwise gives the same state as twisting that side twice counter clockwise. Also we don't nessecarily need to move $1$ side twice in a row. This is were I get stuck.

**Questions:**

1. Is what I've done for the first question regarding only 1 move correct?
2. In order to solve question **2)** I assume I need a general expression for the number of unique states one can obtain with $n$ moves. But my brain seems to protest here. Any suggestions on a good start/strategy?

Comment: For question 1, you seem to be missing all the cases where one is twisting two different sides. And I'm not sure I would include the solved state as the question is written.

Comment: "*Using only 1 move*" I interpret this as being *exactly* one move, not *at most* one move.  The solved state cannot be achieved using *exactly* one move and so shouldn't be counted.  For two moves, things get much more complicated as you are not required to move the same face twice in a row, you can move one face once and then a different face.

Comment: @Dubs - Well, if we only have one move, then only one side can be twisted either one way or the other. For two sides, yes you're right, I missed those cases. And yeah I was a bit unsure of adding the solved state. I'll remove it.

Comment: @JMoravitz - Yes, exactly one move. We don't want to achieve the solved state, but we start from there and then count how many possible other states we can achieve using $1,2$ and $n$ moves. About your 2-move comment, you're right. This becomes really hard to think about.

Comment: 2 moves: Using standard rubiks cube notation, you have each of UU, UU', UR, UR', UL, UL', etc... for an upper limit of $12\times 12$ number of states, but we recognize that several of these are duplicates, for example UU', U'U, RR', R'R, etc... all correspond to the solved state while UU, U'U' both correspond to U2 and RR, R'R' both correspond to R2 etc...  There are six of the twelve outcomes corresponding to halfturns that are duplicates, and there are 12 outcomes corresponding to the solved state and we want only one, so $12\times 12 - 6 - 11$ by my count.  (Note: RU is different than UR).

Comment: For 2, have a look at the so-called superflip.